# Accumulating values that are input into single Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a cell in Excel that resets every time I put a value into it and every value that I put in the cell is stored and added together.

So basically cell A1 would be empty and then I add a value 30, for example. The cell would then store that value and reset to receive more inputs. I then go ahead and put another value in cell A1, 20. The cell should once again reset, but the value stored in cell A1 would now be equal to 50.

I'm very new to VBA so I'm still trying to figure everything out. I tried using some code I found in another post, but was not able to make it work so I was wondering if anyone had any idea on how to proceed with this problem.

This is the code I found and wasn't able to make it work. It was supposed to receive a value in cell A1 and store the same in cell A2, and once you add a new value to A1, it adds it to the previous value in A2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Cells(1, 1).Value <> gdDouble Then
    gdDouble = Cells(1, 1).Value
    Cells(2, 1).Value = Cells(2, 1).Value + Cells(1, 1).Value
End If

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    gdDouble = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
End Sub
```

And in the standard module:

```
dim gdDouble as double
```

Thank you

Comment: Using a global variable makes your accumulated value pretty vulnerable - if you have an unhandled error then you will lose the value.  You might want to store the value in (eg) a workbook Name or on a hidden sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the code in the worksheet_change event like that

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo EH
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Target.Value = Target.Value + gdDouble
    gdDouble = Target.Value

EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

And change gdDouble to a public variable

```
Public gdDouble   As Double
```